# Lithuanian noun translation in conjunction with numerals in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

An important question came up when I tried to translate an existing iOS application into Lithuanian. I know how the Apple translation system works, especially for languages like English or Hungarian. But how I have to translate Lithuanian nouns in combination with numerals I don’t know.

The Lithuanian grammar in conjunction with numerals works like this for the word "įvykis" (event):

```
Lithuanian                  English
0 įvykių                    0 events
1 įvykis                    1 event
2 - 9 įvykiai               2 - 9 events
10 - 20 įvykių              10 - 20 events
21 įvykis                   21 events
22 -29 įvykiai              22 - 29 events
30 įvykių                   30 events
the same logic continuous
as of 21
```

More information about Lithuanian noun declension by numerals can be found in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_grammar#Noun_modification_by_numeral).

My question is, what key values have to be filled into the "Localizable.stringsdict" for Lithuanian? For English this file looks like this:

[image: Localization.stringdict for English]

and for Lithuanian the same file looks this:

[image: Localization.stringdict for Lithuanian]

Those entries in the last table just partly correct. Does anyone know which keys I have to use in order to map my table into the stringsdict table? Which keys/keywords are necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `stringsdict` file you can only have the keys `zero`, `one`, `two`, `few`, `many`, and `other`. That is all you actually need. iOS has its own data (based on information from the Unicode standard) that tells it which of those keys to use based on the actual number.

This is covered in the (now archived) [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH1-SW1), specifically the [Handling Noun Plurals and Units Of Measure](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW10) chapter with specifics about the `stringsdict` file in [Appendix C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH16-SW1).

You may also find language specific rules from [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html). Scroll down to [Lithianian](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#lt) and you will see the built in rules on how the category is used with a given number.

In short, you want the following for your "events" in Lithuanian:

```
one - %d įvykis
few - %d įvykiai
other - %d įvykių
```

iOS will know to use `one` for 1, 21, 31, 41, etc. It will know to use `few` for 2~9, 22~29, etc. It will know to use `other` for 0, 10~20, 30, etc.